# Adding geographic polygons via readOGR / addPolygon() with Leaflet in R

Tags: r, leaflet, visualization

I've been following this tutorial, but for some reason I can't seem to get these borough polygons to show up in leaflet.  If I do

```
plot(boroughs)
```

everything works fine, you can clearly see the shapefile is loaded and ready to use.  Nonetheless, with the below code it doesn't work.  What am I missing to get these shapes to show up on my leaflet map?

```
#load libraries
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)

#available at http://www1.nyc.gov/assets/planning/download/zip/data-maps/open-data/nybb_15d.zip
boroughs <-readOGR("C:/Users/580048/Documents/nybb_15b/nybb.shp","nybb")

leaflet(boroughs) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.DarkMatterNoLabels", 
                   options= providerTileOptions(opacity = 0.99)) %>%

  addPolygons(
    stroke = FALSE, 
    smoothFactor = 0.5) %>%

  fitBounds(-73.9, 40.7, -73.7, 40.9)
```

Comment: looks like the data is in UTM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

needed to transform coords, note I'm not sure that's the right projection

```
library("leaflet")
library("rgdal")
boroughs <- readOGR(path.expand("~/Downloads/nybb_15d/nybb.shp"), "nybb")
boroughs <- spTransform(boroughs, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.DarkMatterNoLabels", 
                   options= providerTileOptions(opacity = 0.99)) %>%
  addPolygons(data = boroughs,
    stroke = FALSE, 
    smoothFactor = 0.5) %>%
  fitBounds(-73.9, 40.7, -73.7, 40.9)
```

[image]